# php variable for javascript ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a table that queries from a database that is updated frequently, and where

```
<span id="totalvotes1"></span>
```

and where

```
<span id="totalvotes2"></span>
```

I need to be able to be able to identify those in the line

```
success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes1').text(data); } });
```

in my ajax for each corresponding row queried... the way it is set up right now, my ajax will just display the information back into

```
<span id="totalvotes1"></span>
```

in the last row queried....

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC");
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 0 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");
$sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 1 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");

$count_variable = 0;

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))AND($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))AND($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) ){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    $category = $row['category'];
    $podcast = $row['podcast'];
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];

    $message1=$row2['msg'];
    $mes_id1=$row2['mes_id'];
    $totalvotes1=$row2['totalvotes'];

    $message2=$row3['msg'];
    $mes_id2=$row3['mes_id'];
    $totalvotes2=$row3['totalvotes'];


?>

<table class="content">
<tr>
<td>


<div id="main">
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<span id="totalvotes1"><?php echo $totalvotes1; ?></span><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right">
<br />
<span id="totalvotes2"><?php echo $totalvotes2; ?></span><br />
<span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message2; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
?>
```

here is my general.js file

```
$(".vote").click(function()  
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
    var parent = $(this); 

    if(name=='up')
    {
        $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "up.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes1').text(data); }
    });

}
else
{
    $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "down.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) { $('#totalvotes2').text(data); }

    });
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me out...

Comment: if anyone has links... or examples.... I mean anything would help.... does anybody know if this is even possible or am I just completely screwed...?

Comment: the way to do it would be to encode your result in json -> `json_encode()` and your receiving js to decode it

Comment: thank you, I have absolutely no idea how to work with json or how I'd implement that here but i will go research it. thank you

Comment: still looking for help... I don't understand how to implement json here....

Comment: There are several problems here that may just be typos. Did you copy the code exactly? There are missing quote marks after totalvotes1, for one.

Comment: yea that's just a typo... just edited that quote mark in. im just trying to get the json thing going here...

Comment: 60 views and no answers... is that normal lol? im new to stackoverflow... still need help here...

Comment: where is your up.php? down.php?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a earlier version of your latest question,
[JSON encode, ajax and display back in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017067/json-encode-ajax-and-display-back-in-html)

In my answer on your latest question about this, I've given a detailed example of how to use JSON data between PHP and jQuery.