# JSON encode, ajax and display back in html

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

I need to add something to my ajax request to show it subtracting 1 from "> right now my ajax just adds 1 to the value of "> and I need it to subtract 1 from ">in the same function. I think I need to do it with JSON but I have no idea how to incorporate that into this script... if somebody could show me exactly how that would be amazing. I know my code is sloppy as heck.... bear with me...

btw I know the ajax isn't actually adding and subtracting anything and that it is just demonstrating it for the client, just didn't know any better way to phrase my problem

general.js

```
$(".vote").click(function() 
{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#total_' + parent.attr("id")).text(data); }
});

}
else
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#total_' + parent.attr("id")).text(data); }

});


}

});
```

here is index.php

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a title="vote_down_" id="vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>&key3=<?php echo $totalvotes1;?>&key4=<?php echo $totalvotes2;?>"> <img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>"><?php echo $totalvotes1; ?></span><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right">
<br />
<span id="total_vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2; ?>"><?php echo $totalvotes2;?></span><br />
<span class='down'><a id="vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2; ?>" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
</div>
<div id="message">
<?php echo $message2; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

here is up.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include("config.php");

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

$mes_id1 = $_POST['key1'];
$mes_id2 = $_POST['key2'];
$totalvotes1 = $_POST['key3'];
$totalvotes2 = $_POST['key4'];
$new_totalvotes1 = $totalvotes1 + 1;
$new_totalvotes2 = $totalvotes2 - 1;

$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id1' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

$ip_sql2=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id2' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count2=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql2);


// if the user has already voted, execute script
if($count==0 && $count2!=0)
{
$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes-1  where mes_id='$mes_id2'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "DELETE FROM Voting_IP WHERE mes_id_fk='$mes_id2'";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

echo $new_totalvotes1;

// if the user has not voted, execute script
}
else if($count==0 && count2==0)
{
$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

echo $new_totalvotes1;

}
?>
```

down.php is the same as up.php just with opposite values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to return JSON encoded data, use `echo json_encode($array);` - [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

On the javascript end of things, if you're using jQuery, use [jQuery.parseJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

If you're not using jQuery, you can use [JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

**EDIT**

OP asked for a example of json_parse in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/mxaP6/1/ Is a working example of parsing JSON in jQuery. In a real application, you would replace the string in jQuery.parseJSON() with the string returned from the server containing json data.

A better way to return data than sending an array in parse_json is to make an object, for example:

data.php

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->name = "John";
$data->age = 24;
echo json_encode($data);
```

This would return json looking like this:

```
{"name":"John","age":24}
```

Which would parse to a javascript object. I've included the example data in the jsFiddle

Comment: You will then need JSON.parse on the receiving end in JS don't forget :)

Comment: Well assuming he is using jquery should add this for non jquery users : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON

Comment: `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)` did you learn jQuery before learning actual standard Javascript?

Comment: How is jQuery not 'actual javascript'?

Comment: jQuery is a library for the language Javascript. Javascript is well javascript. jQuery is a library.

Comment: Thus the reason why I posted that in the first place... and yes I know it is a library...

Comment: would I put the array in up.php? and then also, how do I implement  `jQuery.parseJson()` in my ajax...? that is really the part that I don't understand

Comment: like I would put `$array1 = array($totalvotes1, $totalvotes2);
json_encode($array1); echo json_encode($array1);` in my up.php file right?

Comment: Exactly, and that would return that exact array in javascript after you parse it.

Comment: how do I parse it...? that's where I get caught up... I need to look up the definition of parse... lol

Comment: @ChristianStewart if you could help me out and give me an example of how I would implement jQuery.parseJson() in my code that would be amazing... cuz I just can't figure it out...

Comment: Parsing is converting the string returned to a javascript array. Get the result of your HTTP request and pass it into jQuery.parseJson()